# Rendering SSRS Reports in Java

Tags: java, ssrs-2012

I am working a on project which should render SSRS reports in Java.

Below is the procedure that I have followed.

1. Installed Eclipse
2. Created a java project By setting Execution Environment Java SE 1.8
3. Created a proxy using wsimport

[wsimport image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VnpB.png)

4. Added the references for the generated proxy

[added classed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j099u.png)

5. Written this code

   ```
   import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
   import javax.xml.ws.Holder; 

   import  com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ArrayOfString;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ArrayOfWarning;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ExecutionHeader;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ExecutionInfo;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ReportExecutionService;
   import com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver._2005._06._30.reporting.reportingservices.ReportExecutionServiceSoap;


     public class Render {

    static {
             java.net.Authenticator.setDefault(new java.net.Authenticator()   {
       @Override
       protected java.net.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new java.net.PasswordAuthentication("username", "pwd".toCharArray());
       }
   });
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String reportPath = "/Reporting/Customers" ;
   String format = "HTML4.0";
   String historyID = null;
   String devInfo = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar><HTMLFragment>True</HTMLFragment></DeviceInfo>";
   String executionID = null;
   Holder<String> extension = null;
   Holder<String> mimeType = null;
   Holder<String> encoding = null;
   Holder<ArrayOfWarning> warnings = null;
   Holder<ArrayOfString> streamIDs = null;
   Holder<byte[]> result = new Holder<byte[]>(); 

   ReportExecutionService res = new ReportExecutionService();
   ReportExecutionServiceSoap ress = res.getReportExecutionServiceSoap(); 

   BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)ress; 

   bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);  

   ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();  
   execInfo = ress.loadReport(reportPath, historyID); 
   executionID = execInfo.getExecutionID();       
   bp.getRequestContext().put("sessionID", executionID); 

   ExecutionHeader eh = new ExecutionHeader();
   eh.setExecutionID(executionID); 
   System.out.println(executionID);
   ress.render(format, devInfo, result, extension, mimeType, encoding, warnings, streamIDs);

   String resultString = new String(result.value); 

   }

   }
   ```

When I am running this code , i am getting the below error.

```
     Exception in thread "main"    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: The session identifier is missing. A session identifier is required for this operation.  ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.MissingSessionIdException: The session identifier is missing. A session identifier is required for this operation.  Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.render(Unknown Source)
at Render.main(Render.java:50)
```

I am new to java, am I missing something ? I already set session id.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.